# How to uninstall Magic Toolbox in magento

Tags: magento

After the installation of the magic toolbox extension it's not remove so how it is  remove from the admin panel of the magento

Comment: Installed via magento connect ?

Comment: no i have install it from official site of magento

Comment: you have first downloaded and extract in root folder for installation extension ?

Comment: yes i delete from root folder but still it display in admin panel

Comment: Please delete all extesion related files from you installation and after delete cache from admin and check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fully disable module, you need to go to module config file, like app/etc/modules/MagicToolbox_Magic360.xml, and set it’s active parameter to false, like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
     <modules>
        <MagicToolbox_Magic360>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MagicToolbox_Magic360>
      </modules>
     </config>
```

Remember to flush the Magento cache afterwards.